# Angular change url based on selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to improve my links a bit for my angularjs app. I have a simple search page where people can narrow a selection of items by selecting categories on the left, setting price ranges, typing in search key words, etc. This all works great, but the only problem is that if I want to send a link to somebody (or I click back in the browser) all the work I did goes away.

Basically I would my website to have a url something like

```
"abc.com?cat[]=1,2,3&search=helloworld" or
"abc.com#cat[]=1,2,3&search=helloworld"
```

I've heard of angular deep linking, but is this a good scenario for it? Seems to be a pretty big change to my current setup to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $location.search() for this. It will allow you to add parameters to the URL from javascript.

For example, if you add this in the method called from ng-click :

```
$location.search('search','helloworld');
```

The url would change to abc.com?search=helloworld

You can also set objects in the second parameter to have comma separated values.

If you don't want your page to reload when you change the url, you will also have to disable the reloadOnSearch in your router.

More info here : [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location)
And here : [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)